# XML for tagging (scientific) binary files in folder hierarchy

Tags: python, json, xml, matlab, metadata

My question is about architecture:

Given a folder structure containing binary files (of experimental/measured data), I would like to tag these binary files with information for later analysis. A minimal use case would be to add information of temperature and pressure on a certain day in order to filter for certain conditions in later analysis.

My first approach for implementation (according to hints on the web) would be to place XML files next to the binary files and then walk the file system hierarchy with short custom programs in popular scripting languages like Python or MATLAB.
Are there any caveats to this approach?
I would favor simplicity over complexity and the solution would not need to scale to more than 200 folders.

I would have expected this use case to be very common, but I could not find too much information about similar cases online.

Comment: If you are using MATLAB, it has some very powerful datatypes that can allow you to store metadata alongside the environmental information. Worth investigating that rather than re-inventing something yourself

Comment: I think this is indeed very helpful for the environment. I am not so sure to which degree this is helpful for data, which hadn't been generated in MATLAB.